# Does the “a” of “I'ma” extend to other pronouns?

Tags: contractions, african-american-vernacular-english

Consider “I'ma do this” (as in “I am going to do this”). How does the *a* in *I'ma* extend in usage? Does anyone have any usage where it's used with other personal pronouns? I heard in a song recently where the guy said: "they probably still 'a hate", which I took to mean “they probably still will hate”.
The song: https://youtu.be/XXi629ypSwY?t=175 it's at 3:03.
The lyrics: [Royce da 5'9" LA Leakers Freestyle](https://genius.com/Royce-da-59-royce-da-59-freestyle-la-leakers-freestyle-100-lyrics)

Comment: The times they are a-changin'.

Comment: @Rattler But that "a-" is before a participle, not before an infinitive.

Comment: I don't think so. It can *only* be used for 'I'. What's the name of the song?

Comment: What happened to "I'monna"? That seems to be much more common in the United States than "I'ma".

Comment: @SiddBoketto *“I am going to do this”. How does the a in I'ma extend in usage?* Do you mean in speech (pronunciation), or writing?

Answer (score 3):

Very short answer:

It's possible that it should work like this:

I'ma
You gon
He/she gon
We gon
You gon
They gon

---

*I'm definitely no expert in AAVE, so anyone should feel free to make liberal corrections or critiques.*

First, it's worth explaining what *I'ma* means.

The phrase *I'ma* (which is also written *Imma*, *I'mma*, *Ima*, and *I'm a*), is a feature of African American Vernacular English (AAVE) that is used to mark the immediate future.*

Here's a chart you can find on the Wikipedia page on [AAVE:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English#Tense_and_aspect)

Future - Immediate: I'm a-buy it
Future - Post-immediate: I'm a-gonna buy it
Future - Indefinite future: I gonna buy it

In Standard American English, "I'ma do this" would not be "I'm going to do this," but "I'm just about to do this."

You can find a lot of references to this feature of AAVE (I've linked some below), but for whatever reason, they mostly describe only the first person singular form (i.e. "I'ma"). Some of these references do include an alternative immediate-future marker: *finna*.

> *Finna* is  a  future  maker  that  is  exclusive  to  AAVE  though  it  is  believed  to  be  a contraction  of *fixing*+*to*,  which  is  a  feature  of  Southern  White  Vernacular  English  (cf. Bernstein  2003:  114-118). *Finna*  supposedly  indicates  that  the  event  will  take  place  in the  immediate  future  and,  like  a  modal,  ‘it  precedes  non-finite  verbs  which  are  not marked for tense and agreement’ (Green 2002: 70). 18)
>
> a. We finna get back old times.  (Avon, 3.8)
>
> b.You finna go hit a state senator.  (Avon, 3.11)

[JOE TROTTA & OLEG BLYAHHER, Moderna Språk, 2011](http://ojs.ub.gu.se/ojs/index.php/modernasprak/article/viewFile/677/629)

As you can see, *finna* can be used with other pronouns (*we finna get back*, *you finna go hit*). And here's a reference for "he finna", just for fun:

> *Finna*, marks an action as imminent or as about to happen. For instance “He finna go” is equivalent to SE “He’s just about to go.”

[Jack Sidnell, 2002](https://cdt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Outline_of_AAVE_grammar___Jack_Sidnell_2002_1_Afr.pdf)

But, as we read in that first quotation, while *he finna*, like *I'ma*, is used for the immediate future, it appears to have grown out of a different expression.  *Finna* appears to be from *fixin to*, whereas *I'ma* is speculated to be a contraction of *I'm gonna*.

> In AAVE, *gonna* is pronounced in a number of different ways. When *gonna* appears with the subject *I* there are three ways in which it can be pronounced:
>
> 1.*mana* “I’mana see you.”
>
> 2.*mon* “I’mon see you.”
>
> 3.*ma* “I’ma see you.”

[ibid](https://cdt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Outline_of_AAVE_grammar___Jack_Sidnell_2002_1_Afr.pdf)

Sidnell goes on to explain that for other subjects, *gonna* is reduced to *gon*, "as in 'he gon see you.'"

However, this ignores the fact that *he gonna* is also used.  Some researchers have suggested that there's a distinction between *I'ma/he gon* and *I'm gonna/he gonna*. It's been suggested that *I'ma/he gon* marks immediate future (as noted before), while *I'm gonna/he gonna* is used for the remote future, or, on the other hand, that *I'ma/he gon* represents the "pure future", and *I'm gonna/he gonna* “prospective” future.  This latter feature would parallel Caribbean Creoles in which have the same distinction between *go/gon* and *goin/gwine*.

That observation, and in general, the best information I could find on the subject, came from this *Language Variation and Change* article: ["The grammaticization ofgoing toin(African American) English"](http://www.sociolinguistics.uottawa.ca/shanapoplack/pubs/articles/PoplackTagliamonte2000.pdf)

This previous question on EL&A also contains some good information: [What exactly is "I'mma?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130911/what-exactly-is-imma)

---

* Actually there appears to be some uncertainty over whether *I'ma* necessarily marks the *immediate* future, or just the future in general.  This looks like an example of *I'ma* in a more distant future:

> Yes, sir, I'ma stay with the youngsters. When these get too old,  I'ma get some younger ones.

https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2322

Comment: I'ma gonna do it.He'sa gonna do it.

Comment: He's tryna be all cool.

Answer (score 1):

The two lines including the problematic **'a** are:

> We distribute weight then matriculate into real estate
>
> Then we assimilate, powder dealing they probably still **'a** hate

Note that the verbs *distribute*, *matriculate*, and *assimilate* are all in the present simple tense. So it's quite natural to think that so is the verb *hate*.

So the question becomes, why did the songwriter put the **'a** before *hate*? My guess is that it's probably an effort to make these three phrases rhyme and have the same number of syllables (five syllables):

> Then we assimilate: Then/we a/ssi/mi/late
>
> powder dealing they: pow/der/dea/ing/they
>
> probably still **'a** hate: prol/ly/stil/la/hate

Note that *probably* is pronounced as *prolly*, which makes the third phrase one syllable short without the **'a**.

Then, why put **'a**? Because that's a schwa and rhymes with the schwa in *assim**i**late*.

As for *I'ma*/*I'mma*, I think the /g/ sound is first dropped from *I'm gonna* and then the /n/ sound is dropped. But in *they're gonna*, the /g/ sound cannot be dropped in the first place, so **'a** cannot possibly have been from *gonna* after *they*.

Answer (score 1):

The usual pronunciation of the phrase written *I'm going to* varies a lot, since
it's not limited to AAVE, and anyway AAVE has many levels and options. Some usual options in American English include

- /'a:mə/, with a distinctly long (and unavoidably nasalized) initial /a/
- /'amənə/, a three-syllable version; the initial /a/ need not be long

One can also use the full pronoun *I* /ay/, but only in a three-syllable version

- /'aymənə/

All of these are shortenings of the full phrase, officially pronounced (if at all)

- /'ayɛm'ɡowɪŋtu/

but of course no one ever says that except when they're reading aloud.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally solved this. He's actually saying *still'll*. I have found this use a few times and I think it's the usage.

Note: I am the original poster.